# ansible get the interface name by providing an IP address

Tags: linux, ansible

I have two interfaces in machine(linux). One interface has been addressed and second is down without any IP.
Now I would like to get the interface name matched with IP what I provide as value in ansible.

I was trying something like this:

```
    - name: interface name from provides IP
  set_fact:
    interface_name="{{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - "{{ ansible_interfaces | map('replace', '-','_') | list }}"
  when: hostvars[ansible_fqdn]['ansible_'~item]['ipv4']['address'] == PROVIDED_IP
```

It works good when all interfaces have IP address but problem is when one interface has no IP then I have error: 
*'dict object' has no attribute 'ipv4'*

Is possible to get interface name without getting errors?

Comment: Perhaps something like this? `when: hostvars[ansible_fqdn]['ansible_'~item]['ipv4'] is defined and hostvars[ansible_fqdn]['ansible_'~item]['ipv4']['address'] == PROVIDED_IP`. I'm not sure if it supports Python's `.get(name, default)` which would be better in my opinion.

Comment: I tried only `when: hostvars[ansible_fqdn]['ansible_'~item]['ipv4'] is defined` and error the same _"The conditional check 'hostvars[ansible\_fqdn]['ansible\_'~item]['ipv4']['address'] is defined' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (hostvars[ansible\_fqdn]['ansible\_'~item]['ipv4']['address'] is defined): 'dict object' has no attribute 'ipv4'_"

Answer (score 5):

try this playbook, just set the IP you want to search for:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  vars:
    desired_interface_name: ""
    target_interface_name: "192.168.16.200"

  tasks:
    - name: parse interfaces
      set_fact:
        desired_interface_name="{{ item }}"
      when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_{{item}}']['ipv4']['address'] == target_interface_name
      with_items:
        - "{{ ansible_interfaces }}"

    - name: print result
      debug:
        var: desired_interface_name
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using jinja:

```yaml
- name: Get interface name from provided IP
  set_fact:
    interface_name: "{{ ansible_interfaces | map('regex_replace', '^', 'ansible_') | map('extract', vars) | selectattr('ipv4.address', 'match', '192\\.168\\.16\\.200') | map(attribute='device') | first }}"
```

`{{ ansible_interfaces | map('regex_replace', '^', 'ansible_') | map('extract', vars)` gets you a list of interfaces, where each interface is a dictionary with information about the interface. You can then filter and map the list to get what you need.

Comment: If there might be interfaces without an ip address, this fails. To fix this, you need to add `selectattr('ipv4', 'defined')`, resulting in `"{{ ansible_interfaces | map('regex_replace', '^', 'ansible_') | map('extract', vars) | selectattr('ipv4', 'defined') | selectattr('ipv4.address', 'match', '192\\.168\\.16\\.200') | map(attribute='device') | first }}"`

Comment: To avoid the need of escaping regexp, another mode for `selectaddr` can be used: `selectattr('ipv4.address', 'equalto', ip)`